# Using nant to automate a publish of my flex site?

Tags: apache-flex, nant

I am using Flex and I am tired of having to manually place files in the right folders whenever I want to do a publish. I'd like to do a publish when the build suceeds.

Is there a quick way, using Nant (not my current build tool of choice), to automate this? I have a virtual directory on my PC which is my hosting directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

NAnt has a copy task that will let you do this. Just specify the files and folders you want to copy and the target folder.

If you also build your Flex app with NAnt, you could automatically do the build and the file/folder copy.

An example:

```
<copy todir="${build.dir}">
  <fileset basedir="bin">
    <include name="*.dll" />
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/copy.html